# OpenFileDialog is breaking mouseState

Tags: c#, xna, mono, mouse, state

Basically when I try to create OpenFileDialog, by clicking a specific area in the "game", my mouseState, is kept being "Pressed" even though I've released it.

```
OpenFileDialog dialog;
protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {

        if (selectSong.isClicked)
        {
            DialogResult result = dialog.ShowDialog();
            if (result == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                //code;

            }
            else
            {
                selectSong.isClicked = false;
                // Disabling mouse event - because isClicked is always true after using showDialog()
            }
        }
        UpdateMouse();
}
protected void UpdateMouse()
    {
        MouseState current_mouse = Mouse.GetState();
        Console.Clear();
        int mouseX = current_mouse.X;
        int mouseY = current_mouse.Y;
        selectSong.checkCollision(mouseX, mouseY, current_mouse.LeftButton);
        exit.checkCollision(mouseX, mouseY, current_mouse.LeftButton);
        Console.WriteLine("mouse X:" + mouseX + " mouse Y:" + mouseY);
        Console.WriteLine("Left button down:" + current_mouse.LeftButton.ToString());
        // Left button down - after creating Dialog.ShowDialog() is always pressed, even after releasing mouse, and hitting cancel in Dialog
    }
```

Here is a screenshot describing the problem http://db.tt/NVnEUgLI

Comment: Is `UpdateMouse()` being called after the file dialog is opened? (add a breakpoint)

Comment: Sure it is, after adding breakpoint on .showDialog(), and adding breakpoint on my updatemouse() function - it's keep being updated, everytime - and everytime leftbutton is being pressed - even if it's released

Comment: Have you tried Mouse.GetState().LeftButton.ToString() instead to test whether you're updating current_mouse properly?

Comment: just did, and it didn't change a thing

Answer (score 0):

your problem is, that you press the mouse in the gamewindow, and you release it in the openfiledialog. So the gamewindow doesn't update the mouse anymore. I think you can solve this problem when you open the filedialog after the mouse released.
For that you need to remember the value of the last frame:

```
MouseButton last_frame = MouseButton.Released;

protected void UpdateMouse()
{
    MouseState current_mouse = Mouse.GetState();
    Console.Clear();
    int mouseX = current_mouse.X;
    int mouseY = current_mouse.Y;
    selectSong.checkCollision(mouseX, mouseY, current_mouse.LeftButton, last_frame);
    exit.checkCollision(mouseX, mouseY, current_mouse.LeftButton, last_frame);
    last_frame = current_mouse.LeftButton;
    Console.WriteLine("mouse X:" + mouseX + " mouse Y:" + mouseY);
    Console.WriteLine("Left button down:" + current_mouse.LeftButton.ToString());
    // Left button down - after creating Dialog.ShowDialog() is always pressed, even after releasing mouse, and hitting cancel in Dialog
}
```

and on `obj.checkCollision` you need to put

```
    if(state_now == ButtonState.Released && state_last == ButtonState.Pressed &&...)
```

instead of

```
    if(state_now == ButtonState.Pressed &&...)
```